# setDaemon(false) is redundant?

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

wanna ask if the setDaemon(false) before thread start is redundant(in the constructor is already setDaemon(false)) or not, if not what is the difference?
i copied this code from some website anyway.

```
import java.lang.*;

class adminThread extends Thread {

   adminThread() {
   setDaemon(false);
   }

   public void run() {
   boolean d = isDaemon();
   System.out.println("daemon = " + d);
   }
}

public class ThreadDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   Thread thread = new adminThread();
   System.out.println("thread = " + thread.currentThread());
   thread.setDaemon(false);

   // this will call run() method
   thread.start();
  }
}
```

this is the code i got from: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_setdaemon.htm

thanks and regards.

Comment: They're technically *both* redundant in this example, since this thread wouldn't be daemon by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the setDaemon(false) before thread start is redundant  (in the constructor is already setDaemon(false)) or not, if not what is the difference?

It is *not* redundant.  A thread gets its daemon flag from the daemon status of the parent thread that created it.  The thread creating an `adminThread` might already be a daemon thread so if you need to force it to *not* be daemon you need to explicitly set it.

From the `Thread.init(...)` method:

```
Thread parent = currentThread();
...
this.daemon = parent.isDaemon();
```

So if you want a thread to be daemon or not specifically you should set it specifically before `start()` is called.

Couple of other comments about the code.  Classes should start with a capital letter so it should be `AdminThread`.  Also is recommended to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread` so it really should be `AdminRunnable`.  So the code would look like:

```
class AdminThread implements Runnable {
    // no constructor needed
    public void run() {
       ...
    }
}
...
Thread thread = new Thread(new AdminThread());
thread.setDaemon(false);
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is redundant, unless you are writing some concurrent framework that takes Thread objects from unknown sources. In that case, you may want to do that invocation to ensure it's not a daemon.